# How to write a 'try exception' code for StopIteration error in Python

Tags: python, exception

I'm working on analyzing tweets using twitter api and twython library when im trying to search for tweets with an index (to give how many tweets to consider), why I'm accidentally giving index greater than the actual tweets with my given term it is throwing error like below

[ C:\Users\thota\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twython\api.py", line 532, in cursor
raise StopIteration

StopIteration]

How can I write a TRY AND EXCEPTION code to exclude this error and to continue the remaining execution

Comment: Please show your code which produces `StopIteration` exception, so that you can get a reasonable answer. Also, please read how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to catch a "StopIteration" exception instead of trying to improve the code and avoid these kinds of errors.
But if you insist:

```
try:
    #Your code

except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Comment: As every time I cant determine how many tweets are being posted on a topic I can't predict the maximum size of my index so rather I choose to exclude this error when arise that my index is excluding actual number of tweets on a topic, and to continue with the remaining code.